# "Log in with Twitter", now that Twitter Kit is gone

Tags: ios, iphone, twitter

Twitter's doco says in a number of places that *"Log in with Twitter"* is "available for" iOS ([example](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/log-in-with-twitter/login-in-with-twitter)),

but the doco from Twitter on that appears to be plain missing.

TwitterKit is history, it's not really usuable now ([blog](https://blog.twitter.com/developer/en_us/topics/tools/2018/discontinuing-support-for-twitter-kit-sdk.html)),

Unfortunately it's really totally unclear how to correctly implement *"Log in with Twitter"*

- today ('19)
- in iOS
- with Swift

The only feature I want is  *"Log in with Twitter"*, it seems remarkable there's really no information on how to do this in iOS, how Twitter wants us to do this.

What's the solution?

Comment: Now they use mobile single sign on
https://medium.com/the-traveled-ios-developers-guide/ios-11-privacy-and-single-sign-on-6291687a2ccc

Comment: @canister_exister , I truly appreciate that great link, about SFAuthenticationSession, but really it doesn't get any closer to knowing how to do _"Log in with Twitter"_ in iOS!  :O

Comment: (For example, @canister_exister , the only library out there I've seen which encompasses Log-in-with-twitter, and is not half-assed, is this one github.com/mattdonnelly/Swifter ... and indeed I don't think that uses SFAuthenticationSession at all ??  :O  )

Comment: What is the problem to do OAuth? https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/log-in-with-twitter/guides/implementing-sign-in-with-twitter

Comment: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/log-in-with-twitter/guides/mobile-sign-in-flow

Comment: In 2019 ASWebAuthenticationSession and SFAuthenticationSession most secure way to do authorization.

Comment: And also twitter recommend https://github.com/mattdonnelly/Swifter
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/developer-utilities/twitter-libraries

Comment: @canister_exister and guys, if you have an answer feel free to put in - don't let the bounty waste !

Comment: (indeed Swifter is 1st class BTW .. ah I did not see Twitter's reco.  paste that in as an answer, @canister_exister !)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the list of [Twitter libraries](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/developer-utilities/twitter-libraries) you can find that Twitter recommend to use [Swifter](https://github.com/mattdonnelly/Swifter) or you can do OAuth [Log in with Twitter](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/log-in-with-twitter/guides/implementing-sign-in-with-twitter) authorization using [ASWebAuthenticationSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/aswebauthenticationsession).